# Can I commit and share VM options in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, aspectj

To execute my application, or run or debug unit tests, I need to enable various VM options, include `-javaagent:<aspectjweaver-path>` or `-Djava.library.path=<some native lib path>`

I can see how to change these configurations manually in IntelliJ IDEA under "Edit Configurations..."

What, if anything, do I need to check in to my VCS to share these settings with other members of my team, and ensure they pick them up automatically whenever someone changes them in the VCS?

Alternatively is there a way to set these automatically in IntelliJ without even touching the edit configurations? Especially the aspectjweaver. When I build/test my project from the command line using maven this is all handled for me by specifying `argLine` arguments to the surefire plugin, but IntelliJ doesn't respect these settings. Perhaps there are alternative plugins that can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to share your run configuration. It's simply done by checking the `Share` box right to the configuration name in the run configuration dialog:

[image]

Your run configuration will then be saved to `.idea/runConfiguration` (or whatever your settings folder name is).

From [Jetbrains Web Help](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-javascript-debug.html):

> If this check box is selected, the run/debug configurations become available to the other team members.
> The shared run/debug configurations are kept in separate xml files under .idea\runConfigurations folder, while the local run/debug configurations are kept in the .idea\workspace.xml.
>
> This field does not appear for the default run/debug configurations.